# Looking to solve an infinite loop

Tags: vb.net, infinite-loop

I have a piece of code that generates a dungeon in Java and Python but seems to create an infinite loop in visual basic. There might be a slight problem that I'm overlooking.

```
Dim Touching As Boolean = True
    While Touching = True
        Touching = False
        'Run through all the rooms and check if they overlap
        For i = 0 To numRooms
            Dim aPos As Point = RoomXY(i)
            Dim aDime As Point = RoomWH(i)
            For j = 0 To numRooms
                Dim bPos As Point = RoomXY(j)
                Dim bDime As Point = RoomWH(j)
                If (aPos = bPos) And (aDime = bDime) Then
                    Continue For
                Else

                    'Check for overlapping
                    Dim H_Overlaps As Boolean = (aPos.X <= bPos.X + bDime.X) And (bPos.X <= aPos.X + aDime.X)
                    Dim V_Overlaps As Boolean = (aPos.Y <= bPos.Y + bDime.Y) And (bPos.Y <= aPos.Y + aDime.Y)
                    If H_Overlaps AndAlso V_Overlaps Then
                        Touching = True
                        'Find the minimum amount of movment that stops the squares from touching
                        Dim dx = Math.Min(Math.Abs((aPos.X + aDime.X) - (bPos.X + 2)), Math.Abs(aPos.X - (bPos.X + bDime.X + 2)))
                        Dim dy = Math.Min(Math.Abs((aPos.Y + aDime.Y) - (bPos.Y + 2)), Math.Abs(aPos.Y - (bPos.Y + bDime.Y + 2)))
                        If dx <= dy Then
                            dy = 0
                        Else
                            dx = 0
                        End If
                        If aPos.X >= bPos.X Then
                            RoomXY(i) = New Point(RoomXY(i).X + (dx / 2), RoomXY(i).Y)
                            RoomXY(j) = New Point(RoomXY(j).X - (dx / 2), RoomXY(j).Y)
                        Else
                            RoomXY(i) = New Point(RoomXY(i).X - (dx / 2), RoomXY(i).Y)
                            RoomXY(j) = New Point(RoomXY(j).X + (dx / 2), RoomXY(j).Y)
                        End If
                        If aPos.Y >= bPos.Y Then
                            RoomXY(i) = New Point(RoomXY(i).X, RoomXY(i).Y + (dy / 2))
                            RoomXY(j) = New Point(RoomXY(j).X, RoomXY(j).Y - (dy / 2))
                        Else
                            RoomXY(i) = New Point(RoomXY(i).X, RoomXY(i).Y - (dy / 2))
                            RoomXY(j) = New Point(RoomXY(j).X, RoomXY(j).Y + (dy / 2))
                        End If


                    End If
                End If

            Next

        Next

    End While
```

This piece is of code is given room dimensions, checks if they overlap and then shifts them away from each other. I've tried everything, but I can't seem to break the infinite loop.

Comment: You need to at least tip us off as to which line(s) of code we should be looking at.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be in the shifting of the rooms(If aPos.X >= bPos.X), but this is already a small snippet of a loooong piece of code.

Comment: Without even reading past the first few lines I have a question. Does `numRooms` contain the number of rooms? If so, you need to `0 to numRooms -1`.

Comment: Another problem that I should've solved, but that doesn't seem to fix the problem. I've had a second look and it seems like the shifting might not occur as much as it should.

Comment: I don't understand the `If (aPos = bPos) And (aDime = bDime) Then
                    Continue For
                Else` I don't understand the `continue for`. Just test for the `Not` and execute the code that follows it. It will automatically continue the `for next`.

Comment: **"I've tried everything"**.  Have you? Have you really?  Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through the code line by line, comparing the actual state to your expectations?  If so then either you know exactly where in the code that state did differ from your expectations and how or else your expectations are wrong and you need to go back to square 1 and develop a new algorithm.

Comment: Are `dx`, `dy`, `dx / 2`, and `dy /2` intended to be integers? The latter will not be when `dx` or `dy` are odd.

Comment: With all due respect, I think you code needs a few edits before it becomes apparent what's going on.

Comment: Thank you to everyone. Still a bit new to VB and coding in general, you've provided a lot of help.

Comment: Touching = True may cause infinite loop

Comment: I suspect that the main problem is that when you have a room overlapping another, and the room is moved, it stands a very good chance of overlapping another room. You would be better to check the location at generation time.